# Conditional function in R which returns a matrix

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I am sorry in advance if that's a silly question, but I am a bit new to it.
I would like to write a for loop where the input is a time sequence. Based on the time conditions I would like to select either mat1, mat2, or mat3 to substitute the "mat" parameter and multiply it by 2.

output <- mat*2 #general function

For each time point, I need to have an output.

```
time=seq(0,10, by=1)
mat1 <- matrix(data = rexp(9, rate = 10), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
mat2 <- matrix(data = rexp(9, rate = 10), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
mat3 <- matrix(data = rexp(9, rate = 10), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
```

I would like when the `time <= 3` the "mat1" to be selected
when the `time>3` & `time<=6` the "mat2" to be selected
and when the `time >6` the "mat3" to be selected and then multiplied by 2.

I know that all this is a bit sketchy but any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `mylist <- list(mat1, mat2, mat3); lapply(mylist[findInterval(time, c(-Inf, 3, 6, Inf))], "*", 2)`

Comment: Dear Roland. Thank you for your time. I highly appreciate. If I would like at each time point to extract the corresponding mat and specifically the second-row mat[,2]  and multiply it how could I do that? do you have an idea? Now its an a list format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the way, if you want a list of consecutive integers you can simply use `time <- 0:10`

Here is one method

```
lapply(as.character(cut(time,c(-1,3.1,6.1,10),labels=c('mat1','mat2','mat3'))), function(x) get(x)*2)


[[1]]
          [,1]      [,2]        [,3]
[1,] 0.4013379 1.2690301 0.142831401
[2,] 0.1536697 0.1132762 0.040964909
[3,] 0.1412248 0.2209273 0.007446217

[[2]]
          [,1]      [,2]        [,3]
[1,] 0.4013379 1.2690301 0.142831401
[2,] 0.1536697 0.1132762 0.040964909
[3,] 0.1412248 0.2209273 0.007446217

                 ...

[[10]]
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 0.16712782 0.06451693 0.06554605
[2,] 0.03614116 0.18526124 0.46443236
[3,] 0.53055007 0.01203971 0.16585931

[[11]]
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 0.16712782 0.06451693 0.06554605
[2,] 0.03614116 0.18526124 0.46443236
[3,] 0.53055007 0.01203971 0.16585931
```

Comment: Dear Daniel. Thank you for your time. I highly appreciate. If I would like at each time point to extract the corresponding mat and specifically the second-row mat[,2]  and multiply it how could I do that? do you have an idea? Now its a list format

Comment: you can change the `function(x) get(x)*2` to whatever you'd like. `get(x)` is each 'mat' so if you want only the second row you could say `function(x) get(x)[2,]` instead